# Comment traduire « principal » ?

Tags: traduction, informatique

Comment pourrait-on traduire le mot anglais [principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_(computer_security)), utilisé dans un contexte de sécurité informatique?

Il désigne souvent un utilisateur, mais il me semble que ce serait trop réducteur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator)* propose parmi les traductions possibles le mot **mandataire**, qui indique que le visiteur ou l’intervenant dispose d’un droit attesté d’accès.

---

***Édité** suite aux commentaires*, en particulier à celui de *Dignitéveutdire...*

Pour le CNRTL *[mandant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/mandant)* n’a qu’un sens :

> Personne qui donne mandat à une autre de faire quelque chose en son nom.

… et pour *[commettant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commettant)* :

> Celui qui confie à un tiers le soin de ses intérêts politiques ou privés.

Alors pourquoi  *[Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=PRINCIPAL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)* énonce doctement, fiche 20 qu’une « Entité dont l'identité est authentifiée » (*principal* en Anglais) devient une personne physique ou morale qui délègue ses pouvoirs ? … les réponses dénotent le malaise du franglais certifié.

Eu égard au contexte sécuritaire, il semble pertinent de traduire « Entité dont l'identité est authentifiée »  par

> **Entité certifiée**

Comment: Etrange, étant donné que, d'après Larousse, mandataire est le contraire de [commettant](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/commettant/17502/synonyme) (proposé par @mcadorel). Par ailleurs, ce terme est également couramment utilisé pour traduire "proxy".

Comment: @EricCitaire – Le Larousse est ambigu : 
   *— Toute personne ayant sous sa direction des préposés à qui elle donne des instructions et des ordres*, (sens de *mandant*)
    **— Client du commissionnaire,** (Un commissionnaire est celui dont le métier est de faire les commissions d'autrui et, particulièrement, de porter les messages et les bagages.) **qu'il charge d'acheter ou de vendre des marchandises pour son compte**, (sens de *mandataire*).

Comment: @EricCitaire – Selon votre lien : « A *principal* in computer security is an entity that **can be authenticated** *by a computer system or network*. » S’il est authentifié, ce n’est pas lui qui décide ou qui a le pouvoir d’entrer dans un système, il exerce seulement ses droits et devoirs donné par le *mandant*, ici, le service de sécurité de l’ordinateur.

Comment: @EricCitaire – *Proxy* est traduit par *entremetteur* en bon français (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy ) et par *intermédiaire* en français conventionnel, donc ce sont des mandataires chargés par leur mandant (et surtout leur service de sécurité) d’ouvrir les accès aux réseaux, c’est leur mission.

Comment: Je trouve l'introduction du terme mandant ou mandataire également bancale personnellement mais [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=PRINCIPAL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) (voir fiche 20) a _commettant_ et _mandant_, soit disant normalisés AFNOR depuis 1991 ds. « CNTI/CN 27 N 217, Techniques de sécurité" », derrière un paywall. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commettant_(informatique)) propose

> **commettant**

Selon votre public, pas sûr que ce terme soit compris. Sinon peut-être :

> **authentifiable**
>
> **entité authentifiable**

Comment: Cela me dérange un peu d'introduire une notion de délégation avec les mots "commettant" et "mandataire" (proposé par @cl-r). Il me semble que cette notion n'est pas suggérée par le mot anglais "principal".

Comment: @EricCitaire En effet, et puis en discutant avec un adminsys, il semble que commettant ne soit pas tellement usité. `Entité certifiée` proposé par @cl-r me semble plus juste.

Answer (score 1):

Moi je dis simplement ***participant***. C'est un peu plus général que *principal* dans son sens de sécurité, mais le terme convient quand même.

À noter que c'est là un choix personnel, je communique souvent sur ce sujet en anglais mais rarement en français.

Ça peut être n'importe quel type d'entité, pas forcément un être humain.

Je ne comprendrais pas « commettant » et pas forcément « authentifiable » sans explication.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a un interwiki vers la version franco, où le terme utilisé est *commettant*.